Power BI integrated from a SharePoint list
I have a Power BI visualization created via a SharePoint list integration. I can therefore view the visual tools through the SharePoint list.
However, I would like to display the visualizations on SharePoint page via a web part. There is no information I can find anywhere as to how to do this. It seems to be a relatively simple thing, so I find it strange that I can't seem to make it work .

You can use the Power BI web part in SharePoint Online that allows you to easily embed an interactive Power BI report on your page. The embedded reports are fully secure so you can easily create secure internal portals.
Documentation: Use the Power BI web part in SharePoint Online

You can find the detailed steps to add your Power BI report in SharePoint online site page at: Embed a Power BI report web part in SharePoint Online.

This works if I am embedding a PowerBI report into a SharePoint web part. I am trying to do something very similar, but the PowerBI report was from a SharePoint List and the Power BI visualisation was integrated from that list.
